# Слишком сильно тормозит вывод в foreach

Tags: php

Есть определённые функции в файле functions.php, которые подключаются к индексному файлу следующим образом:

```
require('php/functions.php');
$geo = LocateUserGeo();
$popular = findPopularDirection();
```

А затем, я делаю вывод в блоки при помощи foreach:

```
$start = microtime(true); 
if( $popular['success'] ) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach($popular['data'] as $type => $item) {
        $dest = iataToCity($item['destination']);
        $orig = iataToCity($item['origin']);
        $imageurl = searchImage(iataToCity($item['destination'], 'en'));
        $currency = getCurrencyCode($geo['country_name']);
        if(++$i == 4) break; ?>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image" style="background: transparent url('<?php echo $imageurl; ?>') no-repeat 50% 50%; background-size: cover;">
            <span class="city-name"><?php echo $dest;?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">      
            <div class="flight-main-info">
                <div class="origin">
                    <h6><?php echo $orig;?><span><?php echo $item['origin']; ?></span></h6>
                </div>
                <div class="destination">
                    <h6><?php echo $dest;?><span><?php echo $item['destination']; ?></span></h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flight-details">
                <div class="airline-logo">
                    <img src="//pics.avs.io/176/58/<?php echo $item['airline']; ?>.png" alt="" title="" />
                </div>
                <div class="detail">
                    <span class="name">Кол-во пересадок</span><span class="info"><?php echo $item['transfers']; ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="detail">
                    <span class="name">Дата отправки</span><span class="info"><?php echo $item['departure_at']; ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="detail">
                    <span class="name">Дата возвращения</span><span class="info"><?php echo $item['return_at']; ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="detail">
                    <span class="name">Цена</span><span class="info"><?php echo number_format($item['price'], 0, '.', ' '), ' ', $currency; ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
            <div class="action-buttons">
                <a href="#">Подробнее</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php   
    }
} else { 
echo '<h4 style="color: #9e9e9e;">Упс, произошла ошибка :(</h4>';
} 
echo 'До оптимизации: 2.22 сек.<br>';
echo 'После оптимизации: '.(microtime(true) - $start).' сек.';?>
```

Путём конструкции:

```
$start = microtime(true); 
//тело скрипта
echo 'После оптимизации: '.(microtime(true) - $start).' сек.';?>
```

Я определил, что работа функций занимает от 0.03 до 0.1 секунд, а вот вывод занимает 2.2-3.1 секунды. В чём проблема такого длительного вывода?

Comment: А как определили что функции отрабатывают быстро ? И это время выполнения одной функции в одном проходе или суммарное по всем, во всех проходах

Comment: @Mike проверял каждую функцию по отдельности, а затем и скорость подключения функций к индексному файлу. Всё происходит достаточно быстро, подгрузка функций занимает 0.3 секунды. Проблема именно в выводе.

Comment: А вы прогоните полный цикл просто закомментарив весь вывод и посмотрите время

Comment: @Mike ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Так если ничего не изменилось значит вывод не виноват, а виновата совокупность вызова всех функций

Comment: @Mike как тогда можно это исправить?

Comment: Тогда надо смотреть что вообще делают эти функции и если вдруг работа перед циклом идет с БД, то вынести получение всех данных в один запрос

Comment: И если например одни и те же города часто повторяются в выводе может кеширование какое нибудь организовать

Comment: Зачем например вы тут `searchImage(iataToCity($item['destination'], 'en'))` используете iataToCity, если город назначения у вас уже есть в переменной dest, небольшая конечно прибавка скорости будет, но все таки ...

Comment: Зачем внутри цикла вызывается `getCurrencyCode($geo['country_name']);` если переменная $geo внутри цикла не изменяется, значит валюту можно получить один раз перед циклом

Comment: У вас неправильно проставленны индексы в базе. Инфа 100% ;)  Плюс получение данных в цикле .

Comment: @E_p индексов в базе, в которой я провожу поиск - нет. Из-за чего, мне приходится искать индекс массива рекурсивно. Из-за этого возможны задержки, но я до конца не уверен. Подтормаживать вывод у меня начал ещё на начальной стадии разработки, и тогда я не обратил на это внимание. Но всё же, что-то подсказывает мне, что виной всему функция рекурсивного поиска(которая и работает медленно)  http://ideone.com/POufhn

Comment: Любая база без индехсов будет очень медленная особенно если вызывать через рекурсию. На моем опыте простая база на 4 таблицы пару сотен записей в каждой без индекса запрос  с join по таблицам вешал сервер намертво на несколько секунд. После индексации  доли секунды и нагрузку на процессор небыло видно. На ваш код в пхп есть функция. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin а ты вообще выборку из своей локальной базы данных делаешь или обращаешься на сторону по API?

Comment: @E_p вот [это](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#91365) == моя функция. Только моя выглядит элегантнее, и кода в ней меньше. Работает точно так же. И по скорости, и по логике.

Comment: @DiGiTAL у меня json-файл с данными лежит на локальном сервере, в соседней папке.

Comment: На самом деле, мне в голову только что пришла гениальная мысль. В одном массиве json-данных содержится 23 ключа, а использую из них я всего 4. Если бы можно было убрать лишние 19 ключей со значениями, то это ускорило бы загрузку в почти 4 раза. Осталось только придумать, как это сделать в огромном файле.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin есть такая штука [MapReduce](https://habrahabr.ru/post/103467/)